# \emph{} no longer works as expected in XeLaTeX / LuaLaTeX

Tags: fontspec, italic, emphasis

Compiling with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, `\emph{}` no longer displays text as expected, i.e. in italics. `\textit{}` works fine. Here is a MWE demonstrating the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

    \emph{lorem ipsum}

    \textit{lorem ipsum}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get :
[image]

I have TeXLive 2016 (MacTeX) installed. I updated it an hour ago with `sudo tlmgr update --self --all`.

I guess there is something wrong but what ? I'd be happy to have some help. Thank you.

Comment: This was already raised this morning (or afternoon or whatever time it is in Australia) on the fontspec issues list https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/254

Comment: it actually seems to be fontspec at fault here rather that lualatex/xelatex as if you recompile your document without the fontspec package it works as expected

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you for the link, I didn't know... Yes @ArTourter you're right, but I need to be able to use `fontspec` anyway :(

Comment: @pictho no there was no reason for you to know, I get mailed if an issue is posted there so easier for me to know:-) I just meant that (a) it's not your fault and (b) Will has already been told:-)

Comment: for now I would just put `\let\emph\textit` in your document so you can carry on. and expect a fontspec update to come soon with a fix.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle great idea, that'll do the job till the issue is fixed, thank you.

Comment: Now fixed in texlive update.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**This is now fixed in the version on ctan and in texlive.**

---

This is a hopefully temporary issue in the latest `fontspec` release, it has been raised this morning as

https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/254

In the meantime if you add

```
\let\emph\textit
```

to your preamble the document will work in the common cases where `\emph` is italic, and then just look out for a fontspec update in the next day or so and remove this line again.