# fontspec-biblatex conflict?

Tags: biblatex, fontspec

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{scottdemartinville1861,
title = {Inscription automatique des sons de l'air au moyen d'une oreille artificielle},
volume = {53},
timestamp = {2017-03-16T21:21:25Z},
langid = {french},
journaltitle = {Comptes rendus hebdomadaires des séances de l'Académie des sciences},
author = {Scott de Martinville, Édouard-Léon},
date = {1861},
pages = {108--111}
}
\end{filecontents} 
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage[notes, natbib,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,omitxrefdate=false,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex-chicago}  
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\autocite{scottdemartinville1861}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The italics disappear. If I remove `\usepackage{fontspec}` I get the right styling. Is there any solution to this?

[image]

Comment: The same problem appears if I use`biblatex` instead of `biblatex-chicago`.

Comment: I am not reproducing your problem. Are you sure you are *just* loading fontspec? Or are you using it to select a font? If so, are you sure the font has an italic properly set up. Does a simple `\emph{text}` render properly in italic? I'd be very surprised if this was a bug in `biblatex`.

Comment: there was a bug in fontspec for a few days in January which meant `\emph` was broken, have you updated fontspec to the7 latest release?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `fontspec 2017/01/02 v2.5c`. And I have added some text with `\textit`, and that is rendered properly. It's only the citation italics that are removed.

Comment: You are right, `\emph` is broken. Though `\textit` works properly. I don't know the difference between the two.

Comment: This http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350008/emph-no-longer-works-as-expected-in-xelatex-lualatex suggests there have been a fontspec issue, and you should update.

Comment: Incidentally, I've amended your example to the form that is easier to work with (where the `.bib` file is self-contained): worth noting for the future. Since you are working with XeLaTeX and biber, no reason not to use proper accented characters in your `.bib` file.

Comment: Great. I think this question may be closed -- not because it's a bad question but because the problem you had is not likely to be of general interest. Glad your problem is solved.