# Clean way of italicizing whole preface with \emph inside (which will de-italicize)

Tags: emphasis

I would like to set a part of the LaTeX document in italics but with using `\emph{...}` for emphasizing inside. This is easy to do within single paragraph where `\emph` can be easily nested. But since `\text@command` is not `\long`, it does not extend to multiple paragraphs.

If there is no standard way of doing that, I can always use `\bgroup\itshape ... \egroup` but I need to trick `\emph` into knowing it *already* is in italicized text so that it will change back to upright.

I don't find my current solution `\bgroup\itshape\def\emph#1{{\rm #1}} ... \egroup` is particularly elegant. Something better would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** While `\emph` does switch correctly inside `\itshape`, the problem was found to be caused by `\usepackage{fontspec}`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\itshape This is an \emph{emphasized} word.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't have to use `\def\emph` inside `\bgroup\itshape ... \egroup`. `\emph` de-italicizes the emphasis and is nestable.

Comment: @Skillmon `\emph` is not used in emphasis context & does not know the text is already italicized by `\itshape`. So it only switches to italics, producing no visible effect at all.

Comment: I just tried and `\emph` works on my machine inside a `\itshape` group.

Comment: OK, now it's clear. What version of `fontspec` do you have? There was [a similar issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350008/82917) before.

Comment: @campa: 2.5a (packaged in Ubuntu 16.04). That looks like the cause. Thanks for finding out! (Please mark as duplicate and close.)