# IEEETran can't produce italic et al

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

I am trying to submit a paper to IEEE,  I noticed that example papers have Italy `et al.` at their reference section.
However, i just can't get it to work.

I will really appreciate if someone can shine some light on this subject.

MWE below:

```latex
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
% The paper headers
\markboth{Test}%
{Test}
% \IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00~\copyright~2021 IEEE}
% Remember, if you use this you must call \IEEEpubidadjcol in the second
% column for its text to clear the IEEEpubid mark.

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Test
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Test
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

`references.bib`

```latex
@article{tieleman2012lecture,
  title   = {Lecture 6.5-rmsprop: Divide the gradient by a running average of its recent magnitude},
  author  = {Tieleman, Tijmen and Hinton, Geoffrey and others},
  journal = {COURSERA: Neural networks for machine learning},
  volume  = {4},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {26--31},
  year    = {2012}
}
```

Distribution installed with texlive2023-20230313.iso
Xelatex

[image: What i Got]

---

After further investigation, I found that `\emph` or `\textit` have no effect.
Since I am using XeLatex, adding `\usepackage{fontspec}` sloved this issue.

Reference: [\emph{} no longer works as expected in XeLaTeX / LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350008/emph-no-longer-works-as-expected-in-xelatex-lualatex)

But i still don't understand the cause.

Comment: Your source code (and text) lead us to believe that you plan to submit to an IEEE journal. If your paper is accepted, you will have to send the source files to IEEE for editing. I am not sure that their system handles more than `pdfLaTeX` and I would therefore advise against the use of `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec`. In addition, the kind of details you ask for will be handled by IEEE during the editing phase.

Comment: What happens if you list all authors in the `author` field, rather than pursue the current practice of showing just the first two, followed by "and others"?

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should work.

Comment: @Mico Then all authors will be listed in the reference item.

Comment: @KersouMan Thank you for the advice. I will stick to pdfLaTex and stop worrying about those `et al.`s if such is the case. :D